# Compute the number of non statistics majors

Tags: probability

> Let X be the number of statistics majors in a certain college in the Class of 2030, viewed as an r.v. Each statistics major chooses between two tracks: a general track in statistical principles and methods, and a track in quantitative finance. Suppose that each statistics major chooses randomly which of these two tracks to follow, independently, with probability p of choosing the general track. Let Y be the number of statistics majors who choose the general track, and Z be the number of statistics majors who
>   choose the quantitative finance track.
>
> (a) Let n be the size of the Class of 2030, where n is a known constant. For this part and the next, instead of assuming that $X$ is Poisson, assume that each of the $n$ students chooses to be a statistics major with probability r, independently. Find the joint distribution of $Y$ , $Z$, and the number of non-statistics majors, and their marginal
>   distributions.
>
> (b) Continuing as in, find the correlation between $X$ and $Y$

What I did: $P(Y=y,Z=z)=\frac {x!}{{y!}{z!}} r^{y+z}$; How to compute the number of non statistics majors? As far as I understand there is no word about it.

Comment: Since there are $n$ students  and $y + z$ statistics majors, there are $n - (y + z)$ students who are not statistics majors.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig why? Fore example, we have 100 students and 2 statistics majors. You are substracting from the number of students number of statistics majors and recieve number of non-statistcs majors? like 98 non-statistics majors. I assume, that I just don't get the question because of my english. Can you explain to me?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  The number of people who do not major in statistics (non-statistics majors) is found by subtracting the number of statistics majors from the total number of students.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  But... I don't know. I can reproduce the situation when you answer is correct for me. For instance, there are 5 people and 2 apples, then 3 people won't eat a whole apple. However, In case of majors, if we have 100 people and 2 statistics majors doesn't that mean that 99 people can assigne to the 1sth statistics majors and 1 for the second or don't assigne totally. I mean... I don't get it are you making an assumption that every major can accept just one child?